# Java web app on Heroku: Unable to access jarfile

Tags: java, maven, heroku, github, spring-boot

I'm trying to deploy my Java Spring Boot web application to Heroku.

To launch it locally I run:

`mvn install`

and then

`java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/*.war`

So for Heroku I've created the Procfile:
`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/*.war`

I use Heroku Github integration and the application is deployed to Heroku from Github. So I just push it there.

But the application doesn't launch.

`heroku logs --app myapp` gives me:

```
2015-09-09T21:53:25.581128+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/*.war`
2015-09-09T21:53:27.110820+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile target/*.war`
```

`heroku run bash --app myapp` with `ls -a` doesn't show `target` directory.

I think Heroku doesn't build the app. **But what am I doing wrong?** Thanks in advance for you advices!

Comment: When you say "The application is deployed to Heroku from Github so I just push it there" does that mean you are using [Heroku GitHub Integration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration)? Can you check in your [Heroku Dashboard](http://dashboard.heroku.com) to confirm that the deployment was successfull?

Comment: @codefinger thanks for your comment, build log was the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the cause of the error. Here is a part of build log:

```
-----> Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
       Detected buildpacks: Node.js, Java
       See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment
```

According to Heroku [build order](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#default-buildpacks) the application was considered as NodeJS one. So the solution was to set java build pack:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java
```

And then push any change to application to make it rebuilt.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `mvn install` do `mvn package` to know the difference check http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

> Deploying a WAR file with the Heroku Maven plugin allows you to
>   integrate the deployment process with your existing Maven process. The
>   Heroku plugin uses the artifacts generate by your mvn package phase,
>   and builds them into a Slug file that is uploaded to the Heroku
>   servers.
>
> In this way, the Heroku Maven plugin avoids the overhead of
>   recompiling your project remotely. This is often the preferred
>   approach when deploying from a CI server, which may already have built
>   your WAR file and tested it.

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment#deployment-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin

Regarding deploying Spring Boot, there are some steps to be taken:

- Configure port

  `web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`
- Specify JDK, default is 1.8 (No need to change if 1.8 is specified in Maven)

Check http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cloud-deployment-heroku.html

To execute Procfile use `heroku local`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know about the Maven Heroku plugin but I wish to use Heroku through its Github integration. Also I believe maven `install` step is invoked after `package` and the result (built war file) is the same so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Packaging part in pom.xml should be always war, not jar
2. Putting java buildpack with priority 1 and nodejs with priority 2 also helped

Answer (score 0):

Changing Packaging from jar to war in the pom.xml worked well for me